# Getting 404 response becaues ajaxSetup adds timestamp to GET parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have used 
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); 
to stop caching of file in browser but it appends timestamp in along with GET request and now I'm getting 404-file not found response from server when requesting file using $.getJSON() because of this parameter after file url >?*=1413455027207

 >>>i.e. "[http://test.com/objListObjlist.json?](http://test.com/objListObjlist.json?_=1413455027207)*=1413455027207 "

Anybody have any solution how can i handle this parameter in GET request??
and yes I'm using HTML,Javascript only :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding query string doeas not change the file requested by client. It is just for sending additional data to the server. Make sure you are able to get the file without query string.

```
Note: Appending additional unique query parameter(normally current date-time stamp) is cross-platform recommended approach for cache killing.
Refer the below Mozilla Dev link
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Bypassing_the_cache